# How do I disable/enable a button based on the return value of a method in React?

Tags: reactjs, methods, boolean, jsx

I'm attemping to use a method to toggle whether disabled is true/false on a button in JSX. The issue is when trying to implement it actually locks up my browser. Here is my code:

```
this.state = {
   statusArray = [false, false, false]
}

checkDisable = () => {
   const temp = this.state.statusArray;
   let answer = true;
   for (let i = 0; i < temp.length; i + 1) {
     answer = answer && temp[i];
   }
   return answer;
}

<button
   className={!this.checkDisable() ? 'disabled' : 'continueBtn'}
   disabled={!this.checkDisable()}
   onClick={() => this.handleCardSubmit()}>
</button>
```

Basically I'm tryin to set the value of disabled to be a boolean which is returned by checkDisable(). The value of the items in status array are tied to certain inputs. Each item updates to true if a value in the input field meets a condition which is tracked by status. checkDisable() returns true/false whenever all items in statusArray are true. I want to then enable the button if checkDisable returns true.

Comment: Try to change `disabled={!this.checkDisable()}` to `disabled={this.state.disable}` and set this state of boolean disable in your checkDisable() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make something display based on a value, I would use the ternary && operator like this in your JSX...

```
{displayButton && <button onClick={() => this.handleCardSubmit()} >Submit</button>}
```

With the ternary && operator, only if the expression is truthy will it display the subsequent component.

You then can keep a reference to whether it is true or false in your state:

```
this.state = {
   statusArray = [false, false, false],
   displayButton = false

}

checkDisable = () => {
   const temp = this.state.statusArray;
   let answer = true;
   for (let i = 0; i < temp.length; i + 1) {
     answer = answer && temp[i];
   }
   this.setState({displayButton:answer});
}
```

This way, anything anything can call checkDisable and run. Any changes to your state will cause a rerender of the required components and in this case it will be the button if the state changes on `displayButton` method.

Alternatively, you can bypass the method call and state all together by iterating over the array and seeing if any of the results are true. I'm not sure the exact use case you are after but the below is on the basis that if any of the array items are true, the button should be displayed.

```
{statusArray.filter((item) => (item)).length > 0 <buttononClick={() => this.handleCardSubmit()}>Submit</button>}
```

Hope this helps.

Edit: to show the button as disabled, use the same state as above and in your button do this:

```
<button disabled={displayButton}>Submit</button>
```

Comment: Well I don't want to not display the button. I want it to be visible however just disabled. And how is this this.setState(answer) work? Is it setting everything in state as true? I have other items in my state that arent booleans.

Comment: My mistake, simply display the button and use the state variable displayButton in the disabled attribute

Comment: Based on your response it appears I should use `this.setState({ displayButton: answer })`

Comment: I haven't used class based components in React for a long time. With the new hooks in React 16+, functional components are faster, more efficient and easier to code / read. I recommend looking into React hooks and using the useState hook for local state management. It makes it so much easier to keep track of as you can have different variables for each state.